# Will I see people's custom skins in Hypixel servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

If I play, say, Bed wars or any other mini game on the Hypixel servers, will I be able to see people's custom skins?   I'm not referring to official Minecraft skins, I'm talking about ones people created themselves.  Will I be able to see those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! As long as the server is properly configured, skins should be visible to everyone, custom or official.

Steve and Alex are the only fully official skins.

If you want to download a skin, [NameMC](https://namemc.com/) can be used. Simply type in a username.

Comment: Just to clarify, even if I don't download a skin, but create one myself on a program like gimp and add it to my skins library in the minecraft launcher, that will still be displayed on the servers?

Comment: If you apply it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you upload your skin the right way, it will be visible to other players.
You can check it if you press <kbd>F5</kbd> (hotkey to go into third person mode).